# I'm really new to Python, and I was wondering why my "Else:" isn't working

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import random

number = 50
guess = raw_input("Try to guess my number...")

while guess!=number:
if guess>number:
    print "Lower"
elif guess==number:
    print "Correct, you win!"
else:
    print "Higher"
guess = raw_input("Try again...")
```

I'm really new, and I'm wondering why it won't display "Higher" when the number I input is less than the number, plus, how can I make the number random, since randrange(1,100) won't work

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "isn't working"?

Comment: Oh, just edited the post, sorry, pretty new to this site, I've added more details on my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because `raw_input` returns a string.

```
"50" == 50 # False!
```

You will need to ensure you are checking for equality of the same types. Try converting to an int first:

```
int(raw_input("Try to guess my number..."))
```

Of course this will throw an exception if you try to convert a non-numeric string to an int, so you will need some error-handling as well:

```
valid_num = False

while not valid_num:
    guess = raw_input()
    try:
        guess_num = int(guess)
        valid_num = True
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a valid number"


while guess!=number:
    if guess>number:
        print "Lower"
    elif guess==number:
        print "Correct, you win!"
    else:
        print "Higher"
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you use `raw_input("Try to guess my number...")` ir returns a string and `str!=int` in any case so you were running an **infinite** `while guess!=number:` loop, as the condition would always hold true for comparison of a string and an integer.

Another thing was contradicting statements of `while` and `elif`, when you are running a while condition with `while guess!=number:` then how can you expect this `elif guess==number:` statement to run inside the while statement , So the answer would be handle this case outside the `while` loop.

```
import random

number = 50
guess = int(raw_input("Try to guess my number..."))

while guess!=number:
    if guess>number:
        print "Lower"
    else:
        print "Higher"
    guess = int(raw_input("Try again..."))

print "Correct, you win!"
```

Answer (score 0):

raw_input returns a string.  You will want to convert that to an int for your comparison:

```
guess = int(raw_input("Try to guess my number..."))
```

a `str` will never == an `int`

Answer (score 0):

About your randrange problem:

You should use random.randint(a,b) instead. It chooses a random integer between the number a and b (exclusive, I think.)